# How can I split a dataset into training and testing data and plot graphs and matrices in ml5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, tensorflow.js, ml5.js

For a classification problem, I want to split a json dataset into training and testing data, and use the it to train the model and later test its accuracy using testing data. How can I do this in ml5? Even if I manually split the dataset into two separate files, how do I get the actual labels and compare it with the predicted labels of the testing dataset to get the accuracy of the model? I also want to plot a confusion matrix and some other graphs.By setting debug to true I can only see the loss. In ml5 documentation there is a property called neuralNetworkVis where all of the tf-vis operations are organized. But I could not find any reference or examples on it. I would like to know how to use it. Or is there something that I can use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with ML5. You can split your data before training. Then you can use the test data to make a prediction on your trained model. Then you can see in the original test data if the prediction was correct or not (because test data also has a a label). So you need to create a `for` loop to test every testdata, then you can calculate how many were correct.

Comment: I actually wanted to know if there is a function that can do the train test split like in sklearn for python. Thank you for the answer.